# Umbraco Site Deployment

Tags: umbraco

I've an umbraco site which is currently on my localhost IIS..

I've see several hosting and it's have different price plan between umbraco hosting and the asp mvc site hosting..

To make my site live, are I need to choose the umbraco hosting plan, because my logic thing on local my umbraco site work normally in IIS without additional IIS plugin or setup.. So I can just choose the general asp mvc site hosting

I'm new to umbraco and this is my first time deploy an umbraco site..

Any idea guys? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umbraco will run on any standard IIS based hosting that supports .Net and SQL Server. If you're using a SQL CE database rather than full SQL Server (or MySQL), you'll need to make sure that your host supports that too.

Answer (score 0):

Also, ensure your hosting provider supports Medium trust and generally not Shared Server, although I have heard users getting this going.

If its within your budget buying a VM Server and handling the hosting provides total control over the environment.

Have you looked at Umbraco Cloud?